# Chrome doesn't throw an alert box when handling an error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, error-handling, same-origin-policy

The following works properly in Firefox, i.e. the alert box appears when you try to modify an external document. But in Chrome there's no alert:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Frame Selector</title>
    <style>
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame1.html" id="myFrame"></iframe>
    <select id="selector" onchange="setSRC();">
        <option value="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame1.html">Frame 1</option>
        <option value="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame2.html">Frame 2</option>
        <option value="http://www.example.com/">Frame 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="ChangeColor();">Change color!</button>
    <script>
        var myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');

        function setSRC() {
            myFrame.src = document.getElementById('selector').value;
        }

        function ChangeColor() {
            if (myFrame.contentDocument) {
                myFrame.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            } else {
                alert('You cannot modify a document on a different domain!');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the [demo](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4017788/Labs/frame-selector.html).
What's the reason? What's a cross browser solution?

Comment: What does that mean, not "properly" ?

Comment: It doesn't show the alert.

Comment: I have alerts neither in Firefox nor Chrome.

Comment: Just edited it. Sorry!

Comment: What do you mean by properly? What, specifically, isn't working on Chrome/other browsers? Be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try/catch` to catch that security error :

```
    function ChangeColor() {
        try {
            myFrame.contentDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } catch(e) {
            alert('You cannot modify a document on a different domain!');
        }
    }
```